# Is the Far Cry 6 - Stranger Things crossover mission a time limited event?

Tags: far-cry-6

Does the Far Cry 6 - Stranger things crossover mission "The Vanishing" have a limited period of availability, after which it can no longer be played, or will it be playable so long as the base game is playable?

Comment: I played it yesterday, July 2nd 2023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, no it is not time limited.  The DLC has been out since March of 2022 and appears to still be present according to the [Post Launch page](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/far-cry/far-cry-6/post-launch) of the Far Cry 6 website. I also have not found any evidence or indications that the cross over is limited time only.  If it is, it's *quite a long time* at this point.